# how to select the highest values of each row of an array?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on an Windows Forms Application using Visual Studio 2012. Suppose I have an array with dimension M * N, how can I select the maximum value of each row of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over all the rows, and in each row loop over the row itself and find the maximum:

```
function int[] GetMaxValues(int[] Arr)
{
    int[] Max = new int[Arr.GetLength(0)];

    for (int i = 0; i < Arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Max[i] = int.MinValue;
        for (int l = 0; l < Arr.GetLength(1); l++)
            if (Arr[i, l] > Max[i])
                Max[i] = Arr[i, l];
    }

    return Max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[] GetMaxValues(int[,] Arr)
{
    int[] Max = new int[Arr.GetLength(0)];
    for (int i = 0; i < Arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Max[i] = int.MinValue;
        for (int l = 0; l < Arr.GetLength(1); l++)
            if (Arr[i, l] > Max[i])
                Max[i] = Arr[i, l];
    }
    return Max;
}
```